# Opening Command Prompt when application launched

Tags: java, command-line

I have a java program that works entirely through the console. Is there a way to get the console to open if the user doesn't run the program using the command line?

Comment: Yes but then your Programm will not run in this console

Comment: Actually, you could open the command line via a runtime process, then link into its input/output/error streams. You could use System.setOut etc for that. The you'd have the same functionality more or less. Only difference is you'd have to check Ctrl+C and when that command window closes.